How to spawn an Alacritty terminal from another Alacritty terminal that was spawn by Waybar
I'm using a Waybar module in an Arch Linux Hyprland setup, where my .config/waybar/modules.json is set as follows:
  "custom/clusterteleport": {
    "format": " Cluster Teleport",
    "escape": true,
    "on-click": "$(cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh) --class dotfiles-floating -e ~/.config/ml4w/scripts/cluster-teleport.sh"
  },

The terminal is:
cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh
alacritty%

The cluster-teleport.sh is as follows:
#!/bin/bash

sleep 0.1
clear
figlet -f smslant "Teleport to Cluster"
echo

pkill tsh -9
sleep 0.1
tsh kube login cluster
tsh proxy kube -p 8443 > /home/user/log/cluster-teleport-proxy-kube 2>&1 &

# ------------------------------------------------------
# Start K9S?
# ------------------------------------------------------

sleep 0.1

if gum confirm "DO YOU WANT TO START K9S?" ;then
    bash -c "export KUBECONFIG=/home/user/.tsh/keys/cluster/user-kube/cluster/localproxy-8443-kubeconfig && exec alacritty --hold -e k9s &"
    disown
    sleep 0.6
    exit
fi

echo "Press [ENTER] to close."
read

If I open an Alacritty terminal from Arch, the cluster-teleport.sh works correctly. In the end, it opens up K9S in another Alacritty terminal, and the original Alacritty that ran the script can be closed. The K9S will keep running in the new terminal.
However, when running the script through Waybar, it will close the K9S terminal when the original script terminates.
I tried many things while starting K9S, but none of them worked. I tried nohup and similar tools as well. My last attempt is what you can see above.

What is "escape": true in the configuration file for? Have you tried setting it to false?

But if that doesn't work: I don't know anything about this Waybar or its modules, however:
$(cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh) --class dotfiles-floating -e ~/.config/ml4w/scripts/cluster-teleport.sh

is clearly undergoing shell evaluation, otherwise command substitution, command search and tilde expansion wouldn't be working.
Some form of PATH also seems available, since alacritty is correctly searched, found and executed.
Knowing that, in a holy, portable (POSIX) way, you could append this command, that should execute correctly in any POSIX-compliant shell:
exec zsh

which will replace whatever shell is executing the command with an interactive Zsh instance. This at any rate should prevent the process being run in the terminal (likely some sort of bash -c / zsh -c command) from terminating.
I.e., replace:
$(cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh) --class dotfiles-floating -e ~/.config/ml4w/scripts/cluster-teleport.sh

with:
$(cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh) --class dotfiles-floating -e ~/.config/ml4w/scripts/cluster-teleport.sh; exec zsh


Thanks for your kind help! Adding exec zsh did not help but did not break the code either. The escape: true help in escaping the string. https://man.archlinux.org/man/waybar-custom.5.en

@Dyin Hold up, I'm dumb; please try $(cat ~/.config/ml4w/settings/terminal.sh) --class dotfiles-floating -e sh -c '~/.config/ml4w/scripts/cluster-teleport.sh; exec zsh'

Interestingly, this is going to return and give a shell after the final read (enter is pressed) and the new k9s terminal will open immediately. Now, both terminals are open, the original terminal is floating because of --class dotfiles-floating (this is expected). However, when I close the floating terminal, the k9s terminal will also close. This gave me an idea. If I use your solution and instead open k9s in the original terminal & in a non-floating mode, I can do what I want essentially: to have k9s running in a terminal after tsh authorization. This was helpful!

@Dyin Anddd, I'm dumb twice. Now I understand what you're doing. This is basically a shell, running another Bash instance, running alacritty which in turn opens up another terminal, right? Sorry, you explained that and you posted the script as well, but I didn't catch the depth of the issue at first. Do you really need this chain of calls? It feels like some calls in the chain could be avoided?

However If I'm finally on the same page, you want the Bash instance spawned by the script to endure SIGHUPs, so nohup should work, as long as you use it to protect that Bash instance, i.e.: replace bash -c "export KUBECONFIG=/home/user/.tsh/keys/cluster/user-kube/cluster/localproxy-8443-kubeconfig && exec alacritty --hold -e k9s &" with nohup bash -c "export KUBECONFIG=/home/user/.tsh/keys/cluster/user-kube/cluster/localproxy-8443-kubeconfig && exec alacritty --hold -e k9s &" &>/dev/null &, leaving the disown on the line below.

I'm not sure why the Bash instance wouldn't be SIGHUPped when running the script normally though. If I happen to have missed something again I'll have to try in the morning next time.
